# Doctrine average from subquery

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, dbal

Does somebody have a suggestion how to compose the following query with the Querybuilder?

The essence of the query; A Campsite can have multiple reviews, every review has a various number of numeric scores. The purpose of the query is to calculate the avg of every review and then calculate the avg of all reviews.

```
SELECT AVG(reviews.sclr0) FROM (
 SELECT AVG(a0_.score) AS sclr0 
 FROM AcsiCampsiteReview_Score a0_ 
 INNER JOIN AcsiCampsiteReview_Review a1_ ON a0_.reviewID = a1_.reviewID 
 WHERE a1_.status = 2 
 AND a1_.relationID = 'campsite-2014-100011' 
 GROUP BY a1_.reviewID
) reviews
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you going to do after building this beautiful query in an only-for-beginners Querybuilder?